# ES6, pass class method as callback

Tags: callback, ecmascript-6

Let me start with an example :

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.isOn = false;
  }

  general(method) {
    method();
  }

  off() {
    this.isOn = false;
  }

  atTime() {
    // this.off(); --> works
    this.general(this.off); // --> does not work
  }
}

let test = new Test();
test.atTime();
```

I thought I would pass `this.off` as an argument but it seems I cannot.

Here's a live example : https://goo.gl/9hRTTw

Comment: This didn't change with ES6, it's the same issue as always.

Comment: You're right, it's very similar. But still, I do not understand. I tried to use self, I tried to bind(this) but it does not work. If you could modify the demo and send me back the link I would really appreciate @Bergi !

Comment: `this.general(this.off.bind(this))` *does* work. Please show us what exactly you have done.

Comment: Ooooh ok I see ! I tried `this.general(this.off).bind(this);` thanks a lot ! (rewrite it as an answer if you want and I'll validate it)

Comment: Or do it like this? `this.general(() => {this.off()});`

Comment: I like this syntax, thanks @yeouuu :) `this.general(_ => this.off);`

Comment: @Maxime: I won't write an answer, the duplicate already explains everything (including the arrow function solution). Notice that you still need to invoke `off`, i.e. `this.general(_ => this.off())`